# Stopwatch - Setting start date from UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, stopwatch

I have a simple stopwatch that will give elapsed time since the start button was pressed in seconds. What I need is for the start time to be set from a date picker.

How can I get the "NSTimeInterval time;" to equal that of my datepicker? or do I need to do something else in order to set the user's time?

@implementation ViewController {

```
bool start;

// Gets time when the button is pressed.
NSTimeInterval time;
```

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.display.text = @"0:00";

  start = false;

}

-(void)update {

```
if (start == false) {

    return;

}

NSTimeInterval currentTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = currentTime - time;

//  minutes.
int minutes = (int)(elapsedTime / 60.0);

// seconds.
int seconds = (int)(elapsedTime = elapsedTime - (minutes * 60));


self.display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u:%02u", minutes, seconds];

[self performSelector:@selector(update) withObject:self afterDelay:0.1];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
NSTimeInterval timePicker = [[self.datePicker date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
NSTimeInterval currentTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = currentTime - timePicker;
//  minutes.
   int minutes = (int)(elapsedTime / 60.0);

// seconds.
   int seconds = (int)(elapsedTime = elapsedTime - (minutes * 60));
```

Comment: Thanks man! I am getting an 'unused variable timePicker'. Any idea what could cause this? Not sure where to reference timePicker

Using this to declare the datePicker:
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited. :). NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = currentTime - timePicker;

Answer (score 0):

Just save the start `NSDate. Later get the current`NSDate`and use`timeIntervalSinceDate:`or`timeIntervalSinceNow` to get the elapsed time.

Save the start time:

```
NSTimeInterval startTime = [NSDate date];
```

Later:

```
NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = -[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceNow];
```